# Printing an nxm array

Tags: c

I had an assignment to print NxM (containing only *) matrix using recursion with 2 numbers as input (rows = m and columns = n).

I figured it out using and extra function to print out the rows but cant solve it using only one function.

Heres the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int rowPritner(int m){
    if (m != 0){
        m--;
        rowPritner(m);
        printf("*");
        return 0;
    } else
        return 0;

}
int printMatrix(int n,int m) {
    if (n != 0){
        n--;
        rowPritner(m);
        printf("\n");
        printMatrix(n,m);
    } else
        return 0;


}
int main(){
    int n,m;
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
    printMatrix(n,m);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you doycheck the return value from either printing function, they should both

Comment: Replace the `rowPritner()` function in `printMatrix()` with a simple `for` loop to output the stars. VALIDATE the return to every user-input -- especially `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example version without loops and single function recursion:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printMatrix(int rows, int acols)
{
    static int scols;

    // save initial arg columns
    if (scols == 0)
        scols = acols;

    // recurse with decr. columns and return
    if (acols--) {
        printf("*");
        printMatrix(rows, acols);
        return;
    }

    // recurse with decr. rows
    printf("\n");
    if (--rows)
        printMatrix(rows, scols);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int nscan, n, m;

    printf("Enter rows cols: ");
    nscan = scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    if ((nscan != 2) || (n < 1) || (m < 1)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "bad input, nscan %d\n", nscan);
        return (1);
    }

    printf("\nmatrix:\n");
    printMatrix(n, m);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Thanl you very much.

Comment: Welcome. Did you try this version on your system? Mark the answer if it fits your needs or add comment.

Answer (score 1):

Before looking at changing the `printMatrix()` function to handle the output without `rowPrinter()`, let's take care of a bigger problem first. In `main()`, you fail to check the return of `scanf()` inviting *Undefined Behavior* on any errant input. You MUST ***check the return*** of EVERY user-input to determine whether it succeeded or failed before proceeding to use that input in your code. The `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful conversion. You need only check that to ensure valid input, e.g.

```
    fputs ("enter n & m: ", stdout);
    if (scanf ("%d%d", &n, &m) != 2) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

(**note:** it is also never good to leave the user looking at a blank-blinking cursor wondering whether your program is hung or waiting on something. Provide a simple prompt for the information you need)

What does `rowPritner()` do? It simply outputs `m` `'*'` characters. So if you need condense both functions into one, you simply need to replace `rowPritner()` by something that will do that (or preferably `" *"` so you have more of a square `m x n` output).

To do that you can use a simple `for` loop, e.g.

```
void printMatrix (int n,int m)
{
    if (n != 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            fputs (" *", stdout);
        putchar ('\n');
        printMatrix (n - 1, m);
    }
}
```

(**note:** since you make no use of a return from `printMatrix()` and because it is a simple output function that does no critical processing necessary for the continued operation of your program, you can simply make the return type `void`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/stars_recursive_1fn
enter n & m: 10 10
 * * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * * *
```

(**note:** if you do not want the additional space, simply replace `fputs (" *", stdout);` with `putchar ('*');`)

Note also,  you do not use any function that requires that you include `math.h`. You do not need it. Know which includes are needed by your code and don't guess.

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

**All Recursive Within One Function**

Per your comment asking if you could use just one function to output the grid of stars using only recursion -- you can -- but, you need a way to reset the column values after each row of stars is printed. You can do that with a simple global variable, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int cols;

void printMatrix (int n, int m)
{
    if (n != 0) {
        if (m != 0) {
            fputs (" *", stdout);
            printMatrix (n, m - 1);
        }
        else if (cols) {
            putchar ('\n');
            printMatrix (n - 1, cols);
        }
    }
}

int main (void) {
    
    int n, m;
    
    fputs ("enter n & m: ", stdout);
    if (scanf ("%d%d", &n, &m) != 2) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    cols = m;
    
    printMatrix (n, m);
}
```

(same output)

Note, the `else if (cols)` prevents outputting the `'\n'` if `m == 0` such if the user requests a `10 x 0` grid. Using a simple `else` will work in all cases, but will output one `'\n'` for each row requested -- even when the number of columns is `0`.

As noted in the comment, you should always prefer an iterative solution over a recursive one if it is available. Why? Each recursive call is a complete separate function call requiring the setup of a new function stack all the resources a function call requires. If your program recurses too deeply, you will exhaust your stack space leading to StackOverflow.

Comment: I did not know the printf function returned values that was very helpful ,but I was wondering if this can be done using only recursion without for loops in a single function.

Comment: You can do it in one function -- but understand while recursion may be elegant for some solutions, an iterative solution, if available, is always better. Why?? Each recursive function calls requires a complete new function call with a new function stack allocated. If you recurse too deeply, you can easily encounter a StackOverflow (at least your at the right site). I think you can do it all in one recursive function. I'll drop an update in a bit.

Comment: Also note `printf()` returns the number of characters output, `scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions. (it will save you 10-fold if you just spend an hour and read [man 3 scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) and understand in depth how the *format-string*, the *optional-modifiers* and each *conversion specifier* behaves). `scanf()` is probably the No. 1 misused function by new C programmers Then you will know why all user-input should be done with `fgets()` and then parsing of any values done with `sscanf()` -- `:)`